# error: records are not supported in -source 8

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm using the Micronaut framework on Spring Boot. Below is my full Gradle Scan:
https://scans.gradle.com/s/d442mq4icm7qe/console-log?anchor=19

Here is my my Gradle Build I currently have set Java 16 in IntelliJ appropriately.

```
plugins {
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "7.0.0"
    id("io.micronaut.application") version "1.5.0"

}






repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

micronaut {
    runtime("netty")
    testRuntime("junit5")
    processing {
        incremental(true)
        annotations("be.*")
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-http-client")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-runtime")
    runtimeOnly("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic")
    implementation("io.micronaut:micronaut-validation")
    //DGS
    implementation(platform('com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-platform-dependencies:3.10.2'))
    implementation 'com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'com.netflix.graphql.dgs:graphql-dgs-subscriptions-websockets-autoconfigure'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-joda'

}


application {
    mainClass.set("be3.Application")
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("1.8")
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("1.8")
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your Gradle build says Java 1.8 at the bottom.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Gradle build is targeting 1.8 (Java 8).

You need to change this (or remove it) if you are using the Java records feature [released in Java 16](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395), [previewed in Java 14](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/359) and [in Java 15](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/384).

```
java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("1.8")
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.toVersion("1.8")
}
```